# Java: Locking the parent object while a nested child is active (iterator)

Tags: java, multithreading, codenameone

My question is this:  How do you hold the lock on a parent for the duration that a nested child is active?

I am writing a multithreaded Java application using the Codename One development framework where I have a parent class and a nested child class.  The purpose of the child class is to act as an iterator over a Vector.  Now my understanding is that while the iterator is running, the vector cannot be changed.

Here's a very simple code example:

```
public class Parent<E> implements Collection<Object> {

    private Vector<Object> objectCollection;

    Parent() {
        this.objectCollection = new Vector<Object>();
    }

    public Child<Object> iterator() {
        return(new Child());
    }

    class Child implements Iterator<Object> {

        private int index;

        Child() {
            this.index = 0;
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            int size = this.objectCollection.size()
            if (size <= 0) return(false);
            if (this.index >= size) return(false);
            return(true);
        }

        public Object next() {
            Object temp = objectCollection.elementAt(this.index);
            this.index++;
            return(temp);
        }
    }

}
```

What I want to do is while the nested class (iterator) is instantiated, I want the parent instance locked so all other threads coming into the parent will be blocked until the thread that has the iterator is finished and releases it.

I have done some searching on this and found these questions:

[Locking and synchronization between outer and inner class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910773/locking-and-synchronization-between-outer-and-inner-class-methods)

[Acquiring inner-class lock using outer-class locks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798259/acquiring-inner-class-lock-using-outer-class-locks)

[Programming a mutex in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281343/programming-a-mutex-in-java)

[Is there a Mutex in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291041/is-there-a-mutex-in-java)

However, these do not exactly match my scenario.  The only thing that I can think of is to use a spinlock, but that's also not recommended in Java.  So basically, I am looking for a way to do this.  I can code it, I just need an explanation of what to do.

EDIT:

Only one thread would have access to the iterator.  I am trying to stop the parent from being modified while the iterator is active.

Comment: Can you define "active"?  I don't think iterators are the right model for what you are trying to do.

Comment: How many elements will this vector have and how often will it be modified?  [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) might be a better match.

Comment: I define active as having references to the object.

Comment: Java can't detect when an object goes out of scope.  The garbage collector usually runs much later, so an "in-active" object might be sitting around for a long time (possibly forever) before the GC gets around to it.  The only thing I can think of (besides using different requirements) is to add a method call to the iterator to release its resources (and lock).

Answer (score 1):

I think ReentrantReadWriteLock can implement your scenes; but you should use write lock when update the collection; use read lock when iterate the collection;

Answer (score 0):

There is `EasyThread` which allows you to do these things really easy:

```
private Iterator createIterator() {
   if(!easyThread.isThisIt()) {
      Iterator i = easyThread.run(() -> return createIterator());
      return i;
   }
   // create the iterator
}
```

What's happening here is that all the code within "create the iterator" will run within the thread handled by `EasyThread`.